# Try-catch around a choice menu

Tags: java, while-loop, menu, try-catch

I've made a choice menu in a while loop. To make sure that users put in a valid choice, i put the menu itself in a try catch block:

I want the user to get a new chance if an exception was caught, so I put the try-catch block in a while(true) loop. However, using this kind of loop, the part where the actions are coded becomes unreachable code.

Is there a way to do this better?

And an extra question, How do i prevent a user from entering a choice option that does not exist?

```
while (choice != 0) {
    /* Ask for player's choice */
    while(true) {
        try
        {
            BufferedReader menuInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Please choose between the following options:'");
            System.out.println(" (1) Make new animal");
            System.out.println(" (2) Feed Animals");
            System.out.println(" (3) Count animals");
            System.out.println(" (0) Quit");
            System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");;
            choice = Integer.parseInt(menuInput.readLine());
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.err.println("Not a valid number");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to get input");
        }
    }
    // first choice option:
    if (choice == 1) {
        //actions
    }
    // second choice option:
    if (choice == 2) {
        //actions
    }
    // third choice option:
    if (choice == 3) {
        //actions
    }
}
System.out.print("Thank you for playing!")
```

Comment: There should be some condition which *breaks* the loop.  A `break;` statement, for example.

Comment: You can write an extra private method that will validate the input before processing of current choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very simplest way of doing it is to set a boolean flag above your loop:

```
boolean waitingForAnswer = true;
```

and then just change your `while` loop condition to `while(waitingForAnswer)` and set `waitingForAnswer` to `false` after one has been accepted.

You can then use that same structure to prevent them entering 5, or whatever.  Simply tag an `if` on the end there that checks if the value is an accepted one, if it isn't, don't change `waitingForAnswer`

EDIT:
Incidentally, your string of `if` statements at the bottom isn't terribly efficient.  If the user inputs "1" then the `if (choice==1)` block will trigger and it will then go on to check if it equals 2, if it equals 3, etc when we know for a fact it won't.  Use `else if` there.

Another EDIT:
Also, create your input stream reader outside of the loop.  Currently you're creating a new one each time the loop runs.